# Why does it just go to a black screen when the activity switches to this one?

Tags: android

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {
public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            TextView counter;
            Intent i = getIntent();
             String gender = i.getStringExtra("gender");
             counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
                int caloriesBurned = 0; int caloriesConsumed = 0;
                EditText consumedE;
                EditText burnedE;
                String test1, test2;
                test1 = getString(R.id.txtBurned);
                test2 = getString(R.id.txtConsumed);
                try {
                    if (test1 != "" && test2 != "") {
                        burnedE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBurned);
                        caloriesBurned = Integer.parseInt(burnedE.getText().toString().trim());
                        consumedE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtConsumed);
                        caloriesConsumed = Integer.parseInt(consumedE.getText().toString().trim());

                    if(gender.contains("Male") && caloriesConsumed - caloriesBurned > 2000){
                        counter.setText("You are over your GDA of calories");
                    }
                    else{
                        counter.setText("You're a");
                    }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

}

I'm confused, it's not load times as I've left it for a while and it does swap activity and can be swapped back to the original, not black screen activity. Any ideas?

Comment: What does getIntent() resolve to?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting setContentView after super.onCreate().

EDIT:

You also need to do what Mike suggested. That is, your onCreate method should start with a lowercase "O". As the code is currently, your onCreate method isn't getting called, but if you  rename the method correctly, you'll still get the black screen because setContentView needs to be called after you call super.onCreate();

I also looked through the rest of you code for you - you really should move the UI initialization code outside of the onClick listener:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private TextView counter;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
        counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

        }
    }

}
```

This way, those elements only have to be initialized once, not every time the button is clicked. It also makes the code easier to read.